# Some condition to Bolzano-Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove or disprove that an infinite bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point.

I considered the set of all integers less than 2 and getting a contradiction that  it contains all isolated points. 
Is my method right?
Please help.

Comment: But it is disprove for one set

Comment: a limit point with which topology or which distance?

Comment: And how do you take your limit? at  $\infty$ or  at $ -\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the set consists of isolated points is not sufficient to claim that it has no limit point in $\mathbb{R}$.

<sub>Such a set has no limit point in itself, but the bulk of Bolzano-Weierstrass is that a bounded infinite set has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$.</sub>

For instance
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N},n>0\right\}
$$
consists of isolated points, but it has a limit point.

However, the set of negative integers (which is as good as your example, only easier to describe) indeed has no limit point. Suppose $x$ is a limit point: then there is a negative integer $z$ such that $|x-z|<1/2$, which implies $z=x$. But $z$ *is* isolated and so is not a limit point of the set.

Comment: It's great that you mention that isolated points do no imply the non-existence of a limit point. If these isolated points maintain a minimal amount of gap/distance between them then we can say that there is no limit point.